# Overview of Buddhist lists

Tags: pali-canon

Is there a book/website that gives an overview of all the Buddhist lists and explains what their elements mean, and shows how the lists are connected to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact, yes! Here it is: http://www.thedhamma.com/buddhaslists.pdf
I highly recommend it.

Comment: Over 600 lists. Wow.

Comment: Good answer. I was actually going to vote to close this but I'm glad I didn't. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Leigh Brasington has a [good page](http://bit.ly/1pSRn8t) on this. ;-)

Comment: I saw that one, but I wanted something more complete, like Snyder's book.